# Problem with character topology

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, texture-painting, topology

I have some problems with my head topology. My lips and eyes topology is diffrent than topology in other places. Now, I can't paint my texture on the lips and around eye. The topology at these points is slightly shaded. This is my first time with this stuff. Now, I can't finish my work.
Below I added some screenshots which might help you understand me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: perhaps you have flipped normals, try to recalculate the normals in Edit mode

Comment: Looks like there is incomplete retopology going on as well as the shader errors of having inconsistent normals - I wouldn't suggest painting anything until the model is complete and the shading errors are fixed. Nice result so far.